# tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'pcap'

Tags: networking, ip, pcap, rhel, tcpdump

I am using RHEL 5.4, tcpdump is already installed also there is a user pcap but I am getting following message.

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump   
tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'pcap'
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Already tried searching the web, but there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

At times the install that adds the pcap user can have issues so try below command  first and than take the dump

useradd pcap

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo yum install tcpdump
```

or

```
sudo yum reinstall tcpdump
```

Comment: I have tcpdump installed.. it works and responds on all the commands, however, when I write `tcpdump -i interfacename` it responds with tcpdump: Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'..

Comment: I did `useadd tcpdump` then it works on the same case `Couldn't find user 'tcpdump'`

Answer (score 1):

You must dedicate root user on the command line with -Z option:

`tcpdump -Z root`

(uppercase Z)